# Beautiful soup and inspect show different things while scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, inspect

I want to scrape a table from a website. I found all that the 'tr's correspond to the rows of the table, which are under 'table' with class  'StyledTableBody-c11n-8-64-1__sc-8i1s74-0 hLYlju'.
In my code you can see I found the table, however it doesn't show the children. Meanwhile in the inspect section you can see all the children.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/mortgage-rates/'

response = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser') 
table = soup.find('tbody', class_='StyledTableBody-c11n-8-64-1__sc-8i1s74-0 hLYlju') 
table.find_all('tr')


#output is: []
```

I even tried to use the 'tbody' section, but again the search for trs was empty. Can you guys help me how to solve this issue so I can take the rows and scrape the table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried printing the response you get? Is it the same as the HTML you see in the browser?

Comment: Yes I did, it's not, the children (tr,th) are not showing